# Problem with PHP file include

Tags: php, syntax

```
<?php
   $path = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
?>

<?php include $path . 'library/content/header.php'; ?>
```

I can't seem to get this working. Is there an error with the syntax?

Answer (score 3):

You need to include paths relative to the filesystem, not the URL.

For example: `$path = dirname(__FILE__).'/';`

Additional reading:

- [include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path)
- [`include()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 1):

you must enable `allow_url_include` to do that it is default disabled in your ini.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

but since you stay on the same sercer, use a relative path.
eg:

```
$path ='./'
```

Answer (score 0):

When you require an absolute HTTP path to a php file (or any other dynamic file for that matter), you get the parsed output of the file , so you actually include the output of the file, instead of the source code. You can avoid this by configuring allow_url_include but this isn't really best practice.

In order for your code to work correctly, you should include the relative or absolute path to the file on your server. I would also recommend using include_once or require_once.

```php
<?php
require_once('head.php'); // if its on the same folder

require_once('/var/www/head.php'); //full path to file on server

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../head.php'); // relative path to file using the path of the current open file
?>
```

Hope this helps, 
Shai.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You should *never* include remote files. Its obvious, that you want to include a local file, thus its strongly recommend to use local file paths.

```
include '/path/to/file.php';
```

If you *really* want to include remote files, remember, that usually request over 'http://`are executed by the webserver. This means, if you are trying to include a remote file via`http://example.com/script.php` you will usually only receive the generated content, instead of the php-source.

Answer (score -2):

You can't include remote scripts. You are only allowed include local php files, that reside within path range of a php file, you are writing include in.

Comment: Cmon, guys, downvote for strict answer? "This is not strictly speaking the same thing as including the file and having it inherit the parent file's variable scope; the script is actually being run on the remote server and the result is then being included into the local script." That is not "include", as "include" is ment to include a PHP script, not a HTML document. Damn you. To "include remote html", there are couple of other PHP functions, that doesn't need modification of PHP INI.

Comment: All im really looking for here is a simply templating structure so i can have a variable to the root to append to css and js files, plus header and footer includes, that works on my local setup and a final webserver without editing anything, on index.php and /something/index.php, and i can put into somewebsite.com or somewebsite.com/new without editing anything (or just a single variable). Still cant quite get it working...